# table name not mapped using jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Hi i am working on some CURD operation using Spring+JPA. I have created all the class and entity class as per the flow. But when i am running my project i am getting an error saying my **Employee is not mapped**.

I went to few of the solution where they have mention that the query entity name should be same as per your entity class name.I have done that as well but still i am getting the same error.Following is my code.

**Controller**

```
package com.springboot.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.springboot.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.springboot.entity.Employee;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeController {

    private EmployeeDao dao;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeController(EmployeeDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return dao.getEmployee();
    }
}
```

**Dao Interface**

```
package com.springboot.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.springboot.entity.Employee;

public interface EmployeeDao {

    public List<Employee> getEmployee();

}
```

**DaoImpl**

```
package com.springboot.daoImpl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.springboot.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.springboot.entity.Employee;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeDaoImpl(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Employee> getEmployee() {
        TypedQuery<Employee> query = em.createQuery("from Employee e",Employee.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

**Employee Entity Class**

```
package com.springboot.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "emp_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "emp_seq",allocationSize = 1,initialValue = 1, name = "emp_seq")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**Application.property**

```
#JDBC Property

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/emp
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root

# Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
```

**Error**

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employee is not mapped [from Employee e]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employee is not mapped [from Employee e]"
```

Can someone please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `@ResponseBody` annotation.

```
 @GetMapping("/employees")
    public @ResponseBody List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return dao.getEmployee();
    }
```

Also keep in mind that, it is not a good practice to return a list. You better wrap your list into some class, in order to make sure that if in future, you will have to add some field like "description" or any other(doesn't really matter what field), you will be able to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and i will keep in mind the best practice you have told. If I am not @ResponseBody is use to send the result in form of response, but now my problem is with the data base where my entity is not getting map with my database table name can you highlight me on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change "from Employee e" -> "from Employee".

Comment: Thanks for your reply as u have suggested after removing alias e it is giving me same error